# Creating images in C

Tags: c, image-processing

I'm trying to make a fractal image in C. What is the best way to convert a computed matrix to an image? Is there a built-in library or must I use an external one.. if so any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org). [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html)'s an example to open and show an image (using C++, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GD library](http://libgd.bitbucket.org/) is basic but still quite useful. (It's embedded into the PHP language.)

Or, if you don't want to rely on external libraries, output your data to a text format like [PPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PPM_example), and then convert it to a different format in your favourite graphics editor (or a tool like ImageMagick).